# Iterating the rms-function through numbered variables

Tags: string, octave

I have what appeared to me a simple question at first, but couldn't find a solution. Maybe I have been using wrong search terms?

In GNU Octave, I have a number of data channels (20, to be precise) in my environment, called "Channel_1_Data", "Channel_2_Data",...,"Channel_20_Data".
When I run

```
rms(Channel_3_Data)
```

(or any other channel name) I get the correct answer for that channel.
Now, I would like to do them all in one, but

```
for i=20
rms(['Channel_' i '_Data'])
endfor
```

gives me

> error: mean: X must be a numeric vector or matrix
> error: called from
> meansq at line 65 column 5
> rms at line 47 column 5

I also tried `rms(strjoin({'Channel_,num2str(i),'_Data'},'')`, but as I should have expected that didn't help, as `rms` obviously doesn't want a string.
As is apparent, I'm a newbie at GNU Octave and don't really understand the issue here. How can I iterate the argument in a way `rms` will still take it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the data the same size for each channel? If so, then your data should be stored in a multidimensional array with the channel number as the last dimension. If not, then your data should be stored in a cell array.

Comment: Yes, every channel is the same size, usually (depending on the MAT-file loaded) around 1200000x1.
How do I add all of them to one array? Automating this seems to pose the same problem as the one I already have.